# Difficulties to make the .wait() function work with .stop() on a discord button

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, wait

And thank you in advance to whoever wants to help me.

So I created a slash command to create a reminder with 2 buttons to decide what to do next :
The call to the command works, the embed too, the buttons too. But after clicking on the buttons I would like them to stop the "await view.wait()" with the "interaction:discord.Interaction.stop()" to complete the for loop and move to the next line of my reader. However I don't think the "interaction:discord.Interaction.stop()" line works and I don't know why :

```
@bot.tree.command(name='reminder')
async def reminder(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    buttonyes=Button(label="YES", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green,custom_id="1")
    buttonno=Button(label="NO", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red,custom_id="2")
    view=View()
    with open("C:/Users/market.csv","r",newline='') as incsv, open(f"C:/Users/market2.csv","w+",newline='') as outcsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1]=="no" :
                async def buttonyes_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
                    row[1]='yes'
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"Offer is canceled",embed=None,view=None)
                    interaction:discord.Interaction.stop()
                async def buttonno_callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
                    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"Offer is still running",embed=None,view=None)
                    interaction:discord.Interaction.stop()
                buttonyes.callback=buttonyes_callback
                buttonno.callback=buttonno_callback
                embed = discord.Embed(title='REMINDER', description=f'Is your {row[2]} over ?', color=65280, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now())
                embed.add_field(name='Model', value= row[3], inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name='Size', value= row[4], inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name='Price', value= row[5]+f"€", inline=True)
                view.add_item(buttonyes)
                view.add_item(buttonno)
                writer.writerow(row)
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,view=view)
                await view.wait()
            else:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

I don't have any error, but the code and the loop are stopped by the "await view.wait()"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I don't think the "interaction:discord.Interaction.stop()" line works and I don't know why

This line doesn't make a lot of sense syntactically but I'll gloss over that for now. `Interaction.stop()` **literally doesn't exist**, so that line isn't gonna do a whole lot. Not sure what you expect to happen.

Docs for Interaction: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction

You can't just use random functions and hope they exist. Check the docs first. You probably want to call [`stop()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.stop) on the **View** instance instead.

You should be getting an error for this though, so you may not have configured logging properly (or this code is never reached).

Docs for logging: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html?highlight=logging

> buttonyes.callback=buttonyes_callback
> buttonno.callback=buttonno_callback

This is not the way to go for buttons. Don't override attributes in order to attach callbacks. Just subclass `View`, add `Button`s (either with the decorator or using a subclass of Button) and create an instance of it.

Comment: "You probably want to call stop() on the View instance instead."
Thank you, I don't know why I didn't see that !

However now I go to the 2nd row of my for loop (thank you), I arrive at the "await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,view=view)" line, and I don't know why after clicking on a button, this line gives me an error : "discord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before", do you have an idea ?

Comment: You can only respond to an interaction once, as the error suggests. Use followup if you want to send multiple

Comment: Yes, I tried with "followup" by modifying my code so that from the 2nd row and after, it goes through "followup" like this, in 4 lines : if idx==1: / await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,view=view) / else : / await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed,view=view). But I got this error: "discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body / In components.0.components.2.custom_id: Component custom id cannot be duplicated / In components.0.components.3.custom_id: Component custom id cannot be duplicated"

Comment: Again, read the error. You've got two different components with the same `custom_id`. You keep calling `view.add_item` in the loop, so you keep on adding the buttons multiple times every iteration...

Comment: Really sorry I'm very new in the coding, but you have helped me greatly and quickly, thank you very much, now I understood my errors